# Overlap widget inside card widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, overlapping, card

I wanted to place two widgets (a text and a picture) inside a card, however the picture should go over the card as the image shows:

[image: card widget with text and picture]

But I don't know how to make the picture overlapping the card.

This is my code:

```
             Card(
                margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
                color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                elevation: 0,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                ),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
                      height: 70,
                      child: Text(
                        "This is a text widget.",
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Image.asset(
                      'images/picture1.png',
                      scale: 5,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `stack` widget along with positioned widget to achieve the UI

- Stack

  - Card
  - Container

Answer (score 0):

```
 Card(
          margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
          color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
          elevation: 0,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          ),
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
                    height: 70,
                    child: Text(
                      "This is a text widget.",
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Image.asset(
                      'images/picture1.png',
                      scale: 5,
                    ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

you can use stack under card widget

Comment: Thanks for your answere, but this doesn't solve my problem.